# Scala/MySQL Column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework

I'm doing anapplication on scala with a MySQL database and Play Framework, I need to insert values into a table "entite" and in this table I need to check an ID from other table "intervalle_date" and insert in my table "entite" if that ID exist, if it doesn't exist I need to create it inmy table "intervalle_date" and after insert in "entite".

So I do a first request to check if exist:

```
      var intervalle_date_id = SQL(
      """select id from intervalle_date where date_text_debut={date_text_debut} && date_text_fin={date_text_fin}""").on(
        'date_text_debut -> value._9, 'date_text_fin->value._10).as(scalar[Long].singleOpt)
```

After I check if that var is NULL and if it's null I create it:

```
  if(intervalle_date_id == null)
  {
    SQL(""" insert into intervalle_date(date_text_debut, date_text_fin) values ({date_text_debut}, {date_text_fin})""").on(
      'date_text_debut -> value._9,
      'date_text_fin -> value._10).executeInsert(scalar[Long].single)
    var intervalle_date_id = SQL(
      """select id from intervalle_date where date_text_debut={date_text_debut} && date_text_fin={date_text_fin}""").on(
        'date_text_debut -> value._9, 'date_text_fin->value._10).as(scalar[Long].singleOpt)
  }
```

Finally I do my insertions on entite:

```
  SQL(""" insert into entite(entite_type, id_metier, id_service, regles, niveau_detail,
                            niveau_avancement, sources, licence_id, intervalle_date_id,
                            utilisateur_id) values({entite_type}, {id_metier}, {id_service}, {regles}, {niveau_detail},
                                                   {niveau_avancement}, {sources}, {licence_id}, {intervalle_date_id}, {utilisateur_id})
      """).on(
        'entite_type -> value._1,
        'id_metier -> value._2,
        'id_service -> value._3,
        'regles -> value._4,
        'niveau_detail -> value._5,
        'niveau_avancement -> value._6,
        'sources -> value._7,
        'licence_id -> value._8,
        'intervalle_date_id -> intervalle_date_id,
        'utilisateur_id -> value._11).executeInsert(scalar[String].single)
```

But when I run it, i have that error:
[MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'intervalle_date_id' cannot be null]

I understand it, but I don't know why "intervalle_date_id" is NULL ?

Thank's you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you defined `intervalle_date_id` twice: once outside the `if` statement, which can be null; and then again inside the if statement. That second `var` is **never used** - it's dropped immediately when reaching the end of that scope (`}`). Then, your last `insert` still uses the `null` variable outside the if.

All you have to do is remove the `var` keyword inside the `if` to **update** the existing variable instead of creating a new one:

```
if(intervalle_date_id == null) {
   SQL(""" insert into intervalle_date(date_text_debut, date_text_fin) values ({date_text_debut}, {date_text_fin})""").on(
          'date_text_debut -> value._9,
          'date_text_fin -> value._10).executeInsert(scalar[Long].single)
   intervalle_date_id = SQL(
     """select id from intervalle_date where date_text_debut={date_text_debut} && date_text_fin={date_text_fin}""").on(
        'date_text_debut -> value._9, 'date_text_fin->value._10).as(scalar[Long].singleOpt)
}
```